# Issue with Adding the additional scrapeconfigs in kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, logstash-grok, configmap, kube-prometheus-stack

I've Installed kube-prometheus-stack through helm chart.
Need to add additional scrape configs for prometheus.
Created a configmap to scrape the metrics from grok-exporter

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: ConfigMap
 metadata:
   name: prometheus
 data:
   prometheus.yml: |-
     global:
       scrape_interval: 15s
     scrape_configs:
     - job_name: 'grok'
       static_configs:
     - targets: ['grok-exporter:9144']
```

Applied this configmap.
Then created the secret from this configmap using the below command

```
       ""kubectl create secret generic grok-prometheus --from-file=grok-prometheus.yaml"
```

Secret is created.
Then Added additionalScrapeConfigSecrets in the values.yaml of kube-prometheus-stack.

```
 additionalScrapeConfigsSecret:
   enabled: true
   name: grok-prometheus
   key: grok-prometheus.yaml
```

After this upgraded the helmchart

when I check the "kubectl get prometheus -o yaml" able to see the additionalScrapeConfigs are added.

```
  spec:
additionalScrapeConfigs:
  key: grok-prometheus.yaml
  name: grok-prometheus
```

But I got the below error in prometheus output.

```
- lastTransitionTime: "2022-07-30T16:45:41Z"
  message: |-
    creating config failed: generating config failed: generate additional scrape configs: unmarshalling additional scrape configs failed: yaml: unmarshal errors:
      line 1: cannot unmarshal !!map into []yaml.MapSlice
  reason: ReconciliationFailed
  status: "False"
  type: Reconciled
```

Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like indentation issue in the ConfigMap. `targets` should be one level deeper than `static_configs`. Try this YAML.

```yaml
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: ConfigMap
 metadata:
   name: prometheus
 data:
   prometheus.yml: |-
     global:
       scrape_interval: 15s
     scrape_configs:
     - job_name: 'grok'
       static_configs:
       - targets: ['grok-exporter:9144']
```

Comment: After correcting the Indentation also getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. 

additionalScrapeConfigs:

- job_name: "cassandra"
  static_configs:

  - targets: ["cassandra-exporter:8080"]

2. 

additionalScrapeConfigs: |

- job_name: "cassandra"
  static_configs:

  - targets: ["cassandra-exporter:8080"]

3. https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md

I tried these configuration but nothing is working for me. I am trying to setup scrape config for cassandra-exporter.

I have done the above configuration in values.yaml file of kube-prometheus-stack helm-chart https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/Chart.yaml

Any other thing I can try or am I missing anything in above configuration.

Answer (score -1):

The secret should not be a ConfigMap, but a instead the scrape config entry, like documented here:
https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md

```
- job_name: 'grok'
   static_configs:
 - targets: ['grok-exporter:9144']
```

Here is a better documentation:
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/8b45bdbdabd9b54766c4beb3c562b766b268a034/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2691

According to this, you could add scrape configs without packaging into a secret like this:

```
additionalScrapeConfigs: |
  - job_name: "prometheus"
  static_configs:
  - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
```